# Android OpenGLES - Lag between calls to OnDrawFrame on Moto Droid at large resolution

Tags: android, opengl-es

We are currently developing an Android Game using opengles. We are now trying to support different resolutions, however, when allowing for large resolutions, the moto droid we are testing on seems to lag at it's native resolution (800x400). We have the frames locked at 30 fps, and when we check, our game only takes about 15-20 ms to do it's updating and drawing on the droid, however, there is sometimes 30-60 ms that elapses between calls to ondrawframe. My Galaxy S device doesn't have this problem, and when we put the resolution down on the motorola droid it seems perfectly fine.

We've investigated the issue and have found people with what seems to have been the exact same issue but no one could offer a solution. Other games on the market that seem to use opengles run fine on the moto droid.

Is there something we're missing? Something we need to call or do to? There seems like there should be no reason for there to be 30-60 ms between calls to ondrawframe, especially when the native resolution (800x400) isn't leaps and bounds larger than the default of 533x320, or whatever it is that it goes to when not allowing for large screens, so it seems ridiculous for it to be because of a buffer swap. The lag even happens when near nothing is being drawn to screen, so it's not because we're drawing too much.

Any enlightenment or help as to how to fix this would be great.

Comment: You got <supports-screen anyDensity="true"> in your manifest, right? Might possibly be some automatic scaling going on...

Comment: Yes, we have small,normal,large screen as well as anyDensity set to true in the manifest. When taking out the screen support it runs perfectly fine on the droid and the updates/draw take around 16ms, with the screen support in it takes around 20ms for updates/draw...so there is still around 13ms free, but 30-60ms gets lost somewhere between drawing calls when supporting large screens/anydensity that doesn't happen without it.

Comment: Are you using RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY or RENDERMODE_DIRTY? How exactly are you locking your framerate to 30fps?

Comment: We log the time it takes for the update and draw to occur, then sleep the thread for 33-(time for update/draw to occur). I 've never heard of these constants you're talking about.

Comment: I found what you meant by the rendermode's, we're leaving it at continuous I believe as we don't even set it, so I'm guessing that's what it is defaulted to.

Comment: Tried using rendermode dirty, droid still has this "lag" going on, though games like angry birds and glow hockey do not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give more information. If its not because of drawing, then it should be because of any calculation or object allocation code. Allocating Objects often during a game, invokes the GC, which is bad for games.

Things about performance and allocating memory for Android games is explained in the links below.

I suggest you watch these 2 videos done by Google Android Group.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk&feature=player_embedded

Hope that helps in optimizing.

Comment: Yes, we already have dealt with that topic. Most things are pre-allocated in the game, and as I said, on the default resolution it runs PERFECTLY FINE on the Droid, however, when we allow for large screens, it doesn't. The GC can't simply be doing crazier things on different resolutions. The time spent inside our game with GC and everything is less than 20 ms, we can time this. The time between the calls to drawframe however can last up to 60 ms on the droid with large screens allowed, and as I said otehrs I've found this problem posted on another site with no solutionsgc sadly isn't the issue